# SLES12 vim - background changes scrolling + copy paste issues

Tags: vim, sles

I am using gnome-terminal with SLES12 and I encounter an issue where I am scrolling down during showing file in vim, the background color is changing.
Using some exploration during the internet I got the following solution :

```
if &term =~ '256color'
    " Disable Background Color Erase (BCE) so that color schemes
    " work properly when Vim is used inside tmux and GNU screen.
    set t_ut=
endif
```

But using this solution, it creates a new one.
When I copy paste a line from vim and paste it on other vim , the copy consider also the blank lines in as characters , and creates really long lines.

To emphasize, lets say I have the following line which contain 11 char (including the space)
the copy paste consider also the rest of the line (the blank ones) as characters.
I would like that the copy paste would stop at char '*d* '

```
hello world
```

Any idea how to combine a solution for these two issues?

Answer (score 0):

The two issues are completely unrelated.

When you "copy paste a line from vim and paste it on other vim", you are presumably using your terminal emulator's or system's copy/paste feature which have no idea about where what you consider as a line starts and where it ends. The terminal emulator's window is *n* characters wide so a line is *n* characters and that's all they care about.

A much better approach would be to use Vim's built-in `:help y` and `:help p`, which have the same idea of what a line is as you.

But this creates a second problem: the default Vim is generally not built with clipboard support so you can't really use `yy` to yank a line in one Vim and `p` to put it in another one. You will have to install a proper Vim for that: use your package manager for that.

Once you are set, you can yank to clipboard with `"+y` and put from clipboard with `"+p`. See `:help registers` for `"+` and `:help 'clipboard'` if you would like to synchronise Vim's default register with the system clipboard.

That said, why don't you simply open those two files in a single Vim instance?

Comment: I disagree with the comment that it is not related. When I am not using the ```if statement ``` I wrote in the question, the copy paste works perfectly. I prefer not to work on the same vim with different tabs/windows (it is an habit). BTW in SLES11 I did not have these two issues.

Comment: Well, you had a different version of Vim, a different version of your terminal emulator, and a different version of everything in SLES11. Regardless, using Vim's own clipboard support is the proper way to get copy to and from Vim.